# Find length of pd.Series and strip the last two characters Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I am aware that I can find the length of a pd.Series by using `pd.Series.str.len()` but is there a method to strip the last two characters? I know we can use Python to accomplish this but I was curious to see if it could be done in Pandas.

For example:

```
    $1000.0000
    1..0009
    456.2233
```

Would end in :

```
    $1000.00
    1..00
    456.22
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['$1000.0000', '1..0009', '456.2233'])
res = s.str[:-2]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    $1000.00
1       1..00
2      456.22
dtype: object
```

Pandas supports the built-in string methods through the accessor str, from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods):

> These are accessed via the str attribute and generally have names
> matching the equivalent (scalar) built-in string methods

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df_new = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x : x[:-2])
```

Or only one column

```
df_new = df.astype(str).str[:-2]
```